# Getting input value from a Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am new to both modal's and JQuery and I am having a rough time getting two input values.

Modal in View

```
<div class="col-lg-offset-10 col-lg-2">
        <!-- Modal Button-->
        <span class="item-create-button">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createActor">
                <span style="font-size:larger"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add New Actor</span>
            </button>
        </span>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="createActor" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <table class="table" id="createTable">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="col-lg-4">
                                    <h5 style="font-size:x-large"><span style="font-weight:bolder">Name</span></h5>
                                </th>
                                <th class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-1">
                                    <input type="text" name="createName" style="text-align: center; height: 35px; font-size: 20px; width: 100%" placeholder="Name" />
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="col-lg-4">
                                    <h5 style="font-size:x-large"><span style="font-weight:bolder">Birthday</span></h5>
                                </th>
                                <th class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-1">
                                    <input type="text" name="createBirthday" style="text-align:center; height:35px; font-size:20px; width:100%" placeholder="Birth (mm/dd/yyyy)" />
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" onclick="createFunction(this)" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JQuery "attempts"

```
function createFunction(element) {
    var name = $(element).prev("div").closest("table").find("#createName").attr('value');
    var name1 = $(element).prev("div").closest("table").find("#createName").val();
    var birth = $(element).prev("table").next("input.col-lg-7").find(":input:first").val();
    var check = $(element).closest("table").attr("class");
    alert(name, name1, birth, check);
}
```

I have tried finding more helpful examples, but I am just getting lost in regards to how all the search functions work for JQuery (pre, next, closest, find, ect...)

If someone could help me with this AND possibly point me to good article that helps clarify all these search functions I would be eternally grateful! :)

Comment: I swear, I see this question almost every week.

Comment: @NickDugger I appreciated the constructive input! :)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ the jQuery documentation is a great source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parent() and sibling() relationships to get the model body then standard sizzle selection like

```
//.parent() is modal-footer
//.parent().prev() is modal-body
//.parent().prev().find("#createName") is the input element
var name = $(element).parent().prev().find("#createName");
```

I trust that you'll be able to find out the others from here.